# open html page on android webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to link an html page which is included on an external drive (outside the assets folder of the app) to be displayed on a webview.

I have tried all the online answers i have seen so far and it seems to work perfectly when the html is stored on the assets folder of the application and when the webpage is hosted on a server but my problem is getting a local html page to open on the webview.

Below is the `mainActivity.java` sourceCode. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            WebView view;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        WebView view = new WebView(this);
        view.loadUrl("file:///Volumes/EXTSD/MobileSchool/index.html");
        setContentView(view);

        }
```

Below is the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.felixkalu.mobileschool">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

        <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category 
         android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

     </manifest>
```

please help me out of the mess; been struggling with this all day. I use android studio 2.2. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the following as path:

view.loadURL("file:///mnt/sdcard/myfolder/subfolder/index.html");